# Define array when making hash from arrayref

Tags: perl

I am not sure if I am using the correct terminology here but I am trying to loop through an array and create a hash of arrays and values.

Currently my code looks like this:

```
my $endResult;
my $list = $arrayRef;  
my $hash;

foreach my $hash_ref ( @$list ) {

    if ( substr($hash_ref->{ID_NUMBER}, 0, 3) eq 'ABC' ) {

        $hash->{'ABC'}{$hash_ref->{ID_NUMBER}}->{'VEHICLES'} = $arrayRef1;

        push(@$endResult, $hash);
    }

... #more ID number if statementss with different id numbers
```

and I get an output like this:

```
[
  {
    ABC => {
             ABC1234  => {
                           VEHICLES => [
                             { X => 11, Y => 0, Z => 12 },
                             { X => 2001, Y => 100000, Z => 300 },
                           ],
                         },
             ABC56778 => {
                           VEHICLES => [
                             { X => 1324, Y => 0, Z => 234 },
                             { X => 666, Y => 7777, Z => 555 },
                           ],
                         },
    ...
```

But what I want is for `ABC` to point to array of hashes (`ABC1234`, `ABC46778`) instead of how it is. Let me know if I need to clarify better but I cant figure out the right syntax to make this happen when building my hash.

Comment: Are you trying to create XML with XML::Simple?

Comment: @simbabque no, the output is just a Data::Dumper of my hashref

Comment: I know it is. But it looks like you are constructing input for XML::Simple to turn it into XML. I'm glad you are not. :)

Comment: So you want `[ { ABC => [ { ABC1234 => { ... } }, { ABC56788 => { ... } } ], EFG => ... } ]` ?

Comment: @simbabque Yes I believe that is exactly what I want.

Comment: This looks like an incredibly complicated structure, and thus I am suspicious that we have an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) here.

Comment: Yep, I agree @Sobrique. That's why I asked for the XML::Simple. It's certainly not hard to do that. I'm right now struggling to make a working example that is readable.

Comment: Yeah, likewise - I started, and then realised it was annoying difficult without the source data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get your *long keys* into individual array refs, you need to change the assignment of your data structure. I've added a bunch of example data.

```
# input data
my $vehicles = [
    {
        'Z' => '12',
        'X' => '11',
        'Y' => '0',

    },
    {
        'Z' => '300',
        'X' => '2001',
        'Y' => '100000',
    }
];
my $list = [ { ID_NUMBER => 'ABC1234' }, { ID_NUMBER => 'ABC56778' } ];

# output data
my $endResult;
foreach my $hash_ref (@$list) {
    my $hash; # needs to be inside of the loop!
    if ( substr( $hash_ref->{ID_NUMBER}, 0, 3 ) eq 'ABC' ) {
        push @{ $hash->{'ABC'} }, {         # this becomes the array
            $hash_ref->{ID_NUMBER} => {     # and everything below needs
                VEHICLES => $vehicles,      # to be constructed directly
            }
        };
        push @$endResult, $hash;
    }
}
```

This will yield the following data structure (output with [Data::Printer](http://p3rl.org/Data::Printer)):

```
\ [
    [0] {
        ABC   [
            [0] {
                ABC1234   {
                    VEHICLES   [
                        [0] {
                            X   11,
                            Y   0,
                            Z   12
                        },
                        [1] {
                            X   2001,
                            Y   100000,
                            Z   300
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    [1] {
        ABC   [
            [0] {
                ABC56778   {
                    VEHICLES   var[0]{ABC}[0]{ABC1234}{VEHICLES}
                }
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Please note that your choice of variable names makes this very complicated. It's hard to read and will be hell to maintain later. Always pick variable names based on what they represent. Name them something like `$vehicle`, `$ids` or `$stuff_we_need_to_take_care_off_later`, but not `$hash`<sup>1)</sup>.

<sup>1: Unless you work with a hashing algorithm and we're talking about the result. :)</sup>

Comment: This helps a lot, small question: what does the => do in this instance?

Comment: It's a way of indicating a relationship in a hash. E.g. `my %hash = ( $key1 => $value1, $key2 => $value2 );`.

Comment: There is a bit more to it than that, technically. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fat_comma